# Why jQuery code isn't working?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio

I'm learning jQuery and using Visual Studio 2013 as an editor. Here's my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        alert("Window Loaded");
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Document Ready");
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: This is my project structure]

But this code does not alert me when the page is loaded in the browser. I tried it in Chrome Browser.

Comment: You only need either the minimised or unminimised jQuery library, not both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

include only either `jquery-3.1.0.js` or j`query-3.1.0.min.js` you cannot have both included in header

Comment: it still not working. '<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>'

Comment: check your network tab of your browser. see whther you get 404 for jquey .js file . if that's the case then the .js file's location need to be fixed

Comment: Thank you, Now it's working. I messed up with both jquery-3.1.0.js and jquery-3.1.0.min.js file.